# Ruby Shellwords.shellescape for Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows

Normally when taking user input I would do something like `system("echo #{Shellwords.shellescape(data)}")` but on Windows I always get:

```
[2] pry(main)> system("echo #{Shellwords.shellescape(var1)}")
Hello\ \'\ world => true
```

Is there a way I can properly escape for Windows?

Comment: There is no answer and it's already been accepted without an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use 2 parameters with system or exec. The second parameter doesn't need to be escaped because it doesn't get expanded:

```
system("echo", var1)
```